# Сategory and hints are not working

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have a property grid on my app and I have created the following class for it:

```
class NginXConfig
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Category("General")]
    [Description("Defines the number of worker processes. Windows only supports one.")]
    int _worker_processes = 1;
    public int worker_processes
    {
        get { return _worker_processes; }
        set { _worker_processes = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [ReadOnly(false)]
    [Category("General")]
    [Description("Changes the limit on the maximum number of open files (RLIMIT_NOFILE) for worker processes.")]
    int _worker_rlimit_nofile = 100000;
    public int worker_rlimit_nofile
    {
        get { return _worker_rlimit_nofile; }
        set { _worker_rlimit_nofile = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [ReadOnly(false)]
    [Category("General")]
    [Description("Defines the error logging level. Availble options: debug | info | notice | warn | error | crit | alert | emerg")]
    string _error_log_level = "crit";
    public string error_log_level
    {
        get { return _error_log_level; }
        set { _error_log_level = value; }
    }
}
```

On the property grid, when I set the `SelectedObject` - it renders like this:

[image]

1. The category I have defined as "General" is not showing. It's showing as "Misc".
2. The hint `Description` is not showing.
3. Is it possible to define the order in which these fields show on my property grid via the class?

### Edit

This issue is now solved. Here's the working version of my class:

```
class NginXConfig
{
    [Browsable(true), ReadOnly(true), Category("General"), DefaultValueAttribute(1), Description("Defines the number of worker processes. Windows operating system supports only one.")]
    public int worker_processes { get ; set; }

    [Browsable(true), ReadOnly(false), Category("General"), DefaultValueAttribute(10000), Description("Changes the limit on the maximum number of open files (RLIMIT_NOFILE) for worker processes.")]
    public int worker_rlimit_nofile { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true), ReadOnly(false), Category("General"), DefaultValueAttribute("crit"), Description("Defines the error logging level. Availble options: debug | info | notice | warn | error | crit | alert | emerg")]
    public string error_log_level { get; set; }

    public NginXConfig()
    {
        worker_processes = 1;
        worker_rlimit_nofile = 10000;
        error_log_level = "crit";
    }
}
```

Comment: A tip: all your values are shown in **bold**, because you didn't set `DefaultValueAttribute`.

Comment: @Sinatr Is it possible to define the order in which these fields show on my property grid via the class?

Comment: Order is alphabet, easiest is to give category/property appropriate name (e.g. "1.Category", "2.Category", ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define in this way:

```
int _worker_processes = 1;

[Browsable(true),ReadOnly(true),Category("General"),Description("Defines the number of worker processes. Windows only supports one.")]
public int worker_processes
{
    get { return _worker_processes; }
    set { _worker_processes = value; }
}
```

The attributes are for property, not for private variable. And why not `{ get; set; }` without  `int _worker_processes = 1;`.

Comment: if I use `{get; set; }` how can i set a default value?

Comment: @Latheesan, in C# 6.0 easily: `public int worker_process {get; set;} = ...`, **without it - in constructor**.

Comment: @Sinatr i am using C# 4.5 - any solution for that? Because, at the moment, I am setting the defaults like this: `NginXConfig myNginXConfig = new NginXConfig(); myNginXConfig.worker_processes = 1;`  etc... before I set the `SelectedObject`.

Comment: @Latheesan, press F5 and see my previous comment.

Comment: @Latheesan: In pre-C# 6 you can set the default values of the auto properties in the constructor.